# VSTS release - extracting a nupkg file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a nuget package (.nupkg) of files that I then want to unpack to a specific location during a release in VSTS.
there doesnt appear to be a task to do this.

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is that you can extract the package file through [Extract Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/extract-files) task directly (Archive file patterns: `**\*.nupkg`)

Comment: Interesting. i knew that nupkg are really just zip's, but didn't realize the Extract Files task would recognize it as such. Removing my answer as this is more straightforward.